# print values in pdb

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

When I trace to a function, inside the function I would like to print the values of those variable names with underscore in the beginning, eg. `p __seqLen`. It keeps showing `AttributeError: AttributeError("Converter instance has no attribute '__seqLen'",)` I also tried to use `p self.__seqLen`. This is also not working. How can I print those values?

Comment: You could `dir(p)` and find out all the attributes it has. Then print whichever one you want.

Comment: Noufal, p in the context of pdb refers to "print".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
p locals()
p globals()
```

could help.

Comment: This gives the __repr__, how can I have the __str__ ?

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't print the private members values. For that `p self._<class_name>__<private_variable_name> ` is needed as explained in [zeekay's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5959637/2373278) below.

Answer (score 7):

You might be running into [Python's private name mangling](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers). Python will mangle identifiers that begin with two or more underscores and do not end with two or more underscores. It transforms `__somename` into `_Class__somename`.

Comment: thanks for the detail information. I need a quick way to do it. thanks.

Comment: This is the right answer. For the original question, `p self._<Class_Nam>__seqLen` will print the value of variable.